# Apache Kafka JMX Metrics with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, micrometer, spring-micrometer

All,

I have a requirement to expose the Apache Kafka metrics to the spring boot (v 2.3.0.RELEASE) actuator endpoint.

Please note, **I am NOT using** `spring-kafka` library .

I am using the following libraries

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried this `spring.jmx.enabled=true` but seems like this doesnt work. I assume this is happening because spring is not managing the kafka.

Is there a way I can bind these JMX metrics to the micrometer MeterRegistry?

I am able to make this work using the jmx-exporter provided by prometheus, but since that requires an agent running on a different port, I was hoping to make this work with default Micrometer and spring boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`KafkaClientMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaClientMetrics.java), [`KafkaStreamsMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaStreamsMetrics.java) or [`KafkaConsumerMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaConsumerMetrics.java)?
`KafkaConsumerMetrics` collects metrics through JMX but it is deprecated in favor of `KafkaClientMetrics`.

You only need to create them and bind to your registry:

```java
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
MeterRegistry registry;

...

new KafkaClientMetrics(consumer).bindTo(registry);
new KafkaClientMetrics(producer).bindTo(registry);
```

Similarly for `KafkaStreams`:

```java
new KafkaStreamsMetrics(kafkaStreams).bindTo(registry);
```

If Spring does not manage your Kafka components, why do you expect `spring.jmx.enabled=true` to do anything?

Comment: Oh, i forgot about this thread. (I believe we also had a discussion on this on micrometer issues section). So, I was able to resolve this issue. Since my code uses Kstreams, the above configuration doesn't work directly. In order to achieve this with Kstreams, there should be a public method annotated with ```EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)``` and inside that I get the streams instance from ```StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()```... Once thats done, i create an object of KafkaStreamsMetrics using the streams object and then bind it to meterRegistry

Comment: @RahulKumar you save my day!

Comment: @RahulKumar can you pls share the sample code on how to see Kafka producer metrics using Spring boot